# MobileServiceInvalidOperationException with Azure and Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, azure, windows-phone-8, azure-storage, azure-mobile-services

I have a Registration page on a WP8 app and am experiencing a problem when I'm trying to register a user (the app sends some basic fields like e-mail etc.) and sometimes (it's inconsistent) the `MobileServiceInvalidOperationException` exception is thrown, it looks like it could be timing out (the exception says Internal Server Error).

```
        User User = new User
        {
            Name     = UserName,
            Email    = Email == "E-mail address" ? "" : Email,
            Mobile   = Mobile == "Mobile number" ? "" : Mobile,
            Password = GetPasswordHash(Password),
            DeviceId = HostId
        };
        try
        {
            await App.MobileService.GetTable<User>().InsertAsync(User);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.GetType().ToString() + "\n\n" + ex.Message);
        }
```

I've noticed that when it doesn't work, if I try again it usually works immediately, perhaps I should try and call `InsertAsync` again in the catch block?

I'm not sure if the Azure API tries multiple times in the background for me or not.

Understand my question is quite vague but having trouble replicating the error. I have other code that inserts objects and it never fails.

Has anyone else had this same problem?

Comment: 500 should not signify a timeout (but, there's no guarantees) 500 means something went wrong on the server.  This should also not mean a client error, but there's no guarantees with that as well--it could mean you sent something to the server that caused the problem.  Are there any other details in the exception?  It's best to post all the contents of the exception for someone to help you faster and more accurately.

Comment: you *could* try re-inserting; but, you can't use `await` within a catch block, so you'll have to track that an exception occurred.  I would not recommend a loop retrying the insert as this might introduce an infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I will get the full stack trace, when I experienced the problem it was a beta version installed from the store so couldn't see any other information.

Comment: I think the problem may not even have been when trying to insert but it was when I was checking to see if an email or mobile already existed:

Comment: `users = await App.MobileService.GetTable<User>().Where(user => user.Email == Email || user.Mobile == Mobile).Take(1).ToCollectionAsync();`

Comment: Do you have any issues logged in the mobile service logs (in the portal)? Usually when the service returns a 500 response something is logged to the logs tab.

Comment: When I access the logs tab for my mobile service on the Azure portal it says "You have no logs. You use logs to debug your mobile service. You will see them here when you have script errors, debug output, or other important system errors.". Is this something I have to enable first?

Comment: No, it should just be there; can you tell the name of your mobile service and the time in which the errors occurred?

Comment: Why do you need the name of my mobile service? I just got an internal server error right this second.

Comment: I just added an answer with some more information.

Comment: Do you have the response body of the error? You can find it either via a network capture tool such as Fiddler, or by looking at the `Response` property of the `MobileServiceInvalidOperationException` you received (look at the `Content` property of the response).

Comment: StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Internal Server Error', Version: 0.0, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Cache-Control: private
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET,  ARR/3.0
  Set-Cookie: ARRAffinity=3b03f071a509d72a0255821d74f52966c5134dae4350ea7b5b151b5b02d456cf;Path=/;Domain=xxx.azure-mobile.net
  Date: Wed, 12 Mar 2014 12:40:00 GMT
  Connection: keep-alive
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
}

Comment: Think I'm going to open a ticket with Azure's technical support for this one.